# Why do i keep getting build.gradle code errors

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

Yeah so i downloaded a script a long time ago for fun,I have a very poor knowledge of coding. the problem is that the script is kind of old there's the code and it says

build file 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\Myfriend\app\build.gradle': 76: expecting '}', found '' @ line 76, column 6.
}
^

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.5'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.5'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
        implementation project(path: ':nativetemplates')
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
        //Alert
        implementation 'com.tapadoo.android:alerter:4.0.2'
        //Toast
        implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:1.0.5'
        //CircularView
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
        //Picasso
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
        //Loading
        implementation 'com.agrawalsuneet.androidlibs:dotsloader:1.4'
        //Notification
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'

        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
        annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

        implementation 'com.rishabhharit.roundedimageview:RoundedImageView:0.8.4'

        implementation 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0'

        implementation 'com.github.pedromassango:doubleClick:3.0'

        implementation 'com.github.danylovolokh:hashtag-helper:1.1.0'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0'

        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"  
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The error message is telling you to look at line 76 column 6.  What's there?  Should it be a close brace?

Comment: @DougStevenson Line 76 is the last line the one that contains the close brace

Comment: Found `"` ? All libs are written with a `'`. I would say it shouldn't make a difference in gradle, but try to replace the quotes of `com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0` with `'`

Comment: @bytesculptor it didn't work but thank you for your help